# Problem on execute Azure AutoML - azureml.core.authentication

Tags: azure, automl

Execution does not complete.

In the `log` shows authentication `error`.

```
2021-09-29 15:16:08,080 | azureml.core.authentication | DEBUG | Time to expire 1810663.919637 seconds
2021-09-29 15:16:38,080 | azureml.core.authentication | DEBUG | Time to expire 1810633.919396 seconds
```